# How do I determine the maximum allowed size of an MTLTextureDescriptor

Tags: ios, core-graphics, metal, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I am performing image manipulation using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format)`. If the image is too large, it will fail with an assertion:

```
failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has width (15488) greater than the maximum allowed size of 8192.'
```

I'd like to prevent this by first checking the image does not exceed the maximum allowed size. I'm not sure that 8192 is a constant for all devices, and would like to obtain this programmatically instead of hard coding it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get programmatically the maximum texture size (width and height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366416/how-to-get-programmatically-the-maximum-texture-size-width-and-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is programmatically not possible to get the maximum texture size supported by the device. However, the below code will give you the hardcoded size based on the device type.

```
int maxTexSize = 4096;

if ([mtldevice supportsFeatureSet:MTLFeatureSet_iOS_GPUFamily4_v1] || [mtldevice supportsFeatureSet:MTLFeatureSet_iOS_GPUFamily3_v1]) {
    maxTexSize = 16384;
else if ([mtldevice supportsFeatureSet:MTLFeatureSet_iOS_GPUFamily2_v2] || [mtldevice supportsFeatureSet:MTLFeatureSet_iOS_GPUFamily1_v2]) {
    maxTexSize = 8192;
} else {
    maxTexSize = 4096;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a programmatic way to determine the max texture size

A hardcoded conditional statement In swift would be like this

```
static var max1DTextureWidth: Int = {
    var maxLength = 8192;

    // It's recommended to use your shared device
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!

    if device.supportsFamily(.apple1) || device.supportsFamily(.apple2) {
        maxLength = 8192 // A7 and A8 chips
    } else {
        maxLength = 16384 // A9 and later chips
    }
    return maxLength
}()
```

It's important to find the table at Page7 of this doc to keep your code updated every year

https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf

also find this documentation for GPUFamily and chips map

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlgpufamily#3189618